# Doctrine much long time as in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpmyadmin

I am using symfony with doctrine (2.5). I have select (taken from Symfony Profiler->doctrine->queries->view runnalbe query). It takes ~200ms via phpMyAdmin or on web via doctrine (same time).

```
SELECT col1, col2 ... col 12, MIN(t0_.price) AS sclr_24 
FROM tablo t0_ 
WHERE t0_.visible = (1) AND t0_.status <> (0) AND t0_.price IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY t0_.kat_id 
ORDER BY t0_.hotel ASC;
```

But if i remove `orderBy` from php - doctrine will generate this query: (same as previous but without `orderBy`)

```
SELECT col1, col2 ... col 12, MIN(t0_.price) AS sclr_24 
FROM tablo t0_ 
WHERE t0_.visible = (1) AND t0_.status <> (0) AND t0_.price IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY t0_.kat_id;
```

This query takes time nearly previous query BUT only on web via doctrine if i copy this query and paste to phpMyAdmin it takes a lot of time less (~20ms).

Can some explain me why? Or what i must change to have same time as in phpMyAdmin?

UPDATE:
code from repository:

```
$query = $repository
   ->createQueryBuilder('t')
   ->select('t.col1', 't.col2' .... 't.col12', 'MIN(t.price) AS price');

$query->where('t.visible = (:visible)')->setParameter('visible', 1);
$query->andWhere('t.status!= (:status)')->setParameter('splneno', 0);
$query->andWhere('t.priceis not null');

$query->groupBy('t.katId');
$result = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: please add some more information and code how exactly you create and process this query in symfony.

Answer (score 0):

The displayed execution time in 'phpMyAdmin' is how long the query took to run on the server - it's accurate and comes from the MySQL engine itself.

Unfortunately, the results have to then be sent over the web to your browser to be displayed, which takes a lot longer. 'Doctrine2' is ORM and has more overhead with wrappers and other stuff.

Comment: Yes but in Symfony profiler under 'Doctrine' are executed queries for request so, i am not talking about GET request time but about time displayed at specific query in profiler + yes doctrine has wrappers and other stuff but difference between second query is too large in my opinoin. (from my experience difference can be +/-5% no ~1000% something is wrong...)

Comment: Doctrine ORM, like most ORMs, is performing a process called Hydration when converting database results into objects.
This process usually involves reading a record from a database result and then converting the column values into an object's properties.
So you need to configure doctrine to speed up query execution. You can increase speed up to 70% but again its depends on how complex your entities are and doctrine configuration. Please refer this [How to increase doctrine performance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/improving-performance.html)

Comment: question was updated and if that info change anything - i am not using ->getResult() but ->getArrayResult()

Answer (score 0):

This query is ran from a repository?
How is the entity linked to this repository?
Is the time still the same if you run it outside the repo?